# Retrieving Records From SQL server table based on matching Records in an excel Spreadsheet

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, database

I have a data warehouse table with a large number of rowsand I want to do a data comparison with just the cases that are handled by a specific external partner. I have an excel spreadsheet of the cases they handle but I don't have a column in my data warehouse to specify which rows they are handling. The only identifier I have is the list of unique record IDs in the excel spreadsheet.

Is there a way to extract the records in my table without having to load the external data into my database.

Comment: `a data warehouse table with a large number of records` in that case *don't* try to match with an Excel file. Load the Excel data into the database, either in a temporary or staging table, and JOIN with the target table. That will be a *lot* faster than extracting the data from the database

Comment: If the Excel file has a small number of rows, eg 1000, you could create a query dynamically that uses an `ID IN (id1,id2, id3....)` condition to load the rows with matching IDs. For more data you can use a table-valued parameter, although that will be less efficient than using a temporary or staging table. In both cases you'll be sending the IDs to the database though